# Whats the output of this code?

Tags: c#

```
 object nullobject = null;
 object myobject = new myobject();
 console.writeline("nullobject="+nullobject+"myobject="+myobject);
```

Comment: It will probably produce a compiler error, since C# is case-sensitive. Unless you have your own special classes `object` and `console`.

Comment: Why don't you compile it and find out?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: `object` is an alias for `Object`, just like `string` is for `String`, but you're right abut `console`. Even with the compiler error aside, i believe it will throw a null pointer exception trying to concatenate `null.ToString()` to a string.

Comment: @Aren B: I don't think I've seen those aliases before, but it's always good to learn something new!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It (unexpectedly for me, anyway) prints

```
nullobject=myobject=System.Object
```

(changing your `= new myobject();` line to `= new object();` and correcting other typos.)

The thing I didn't know (and the reason I'm bothering to post this) is CSharp treats null string objects as empty strings when concatenating. There's a note halfway down this page about it.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx

```
object nullobject = null;
object myobject = new object();
Console.WriteLine(nullobject + "");         //ok, prints empty line
Console.WriteLine(nullobject.ToString());   //this will blow up
Console.WriteLine("nullobject=" + nullobject + "myobject=" + myobject); //ok, prints what's above.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and correcting my typos (sorry about that)
but what i really wanted to ask here was that what does an object of class Object in C# print when null is assigned to it and
In the second line 
Object myobject = new myobject();
what will be printed now if i try to print myobject.

Comment: When you call `Console.WriteLine(obj)` or `string.Format("{0}", obj)`, `obj`'s `ToString()` method will get called. (The interesting point I wasn't aware of is csharp will use an empty string in place of a null object for most string operations, except for direct calls to `ToString()`). `ToString()` is an overridable method in the `object` type.  Since everything in csharp inherits from `object`, any of your classes can override this and return any text you want.  By default, you will get the name of their type, IE, `System.Object`, above.